# Earning through Ads Admob

Tags: android, admob, ads

I recently started developing a game for android and put the banner ads in it. I have not yet published the game as I wanted everything to be configured first.

So, my question is how Admob earning is calculated and what should I expect in earnings and how can I maximize them. What if no one clicks on Adds and I have like 1000 impressions per day, then what will be my earning.
Also, should I use Admob meditation? (if yes then which network should I add in the meditation)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about how a specific ad service calculates revenue, not programming.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about ad revenues, not programming.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> how Admob earning is calculated

It depends in many variables, the main ones are impression, clicks and advertisers, specially advertisers will vary a lot depending on region your app is used.

> what should I expect in earnings

It is really hard to answer this one, it will depend a lot how much users do you have, on of my apps currently has a little more than 3000 active users (weekly) and 30000 downloads, I have around 3 clicks in a day and get around $4 for month, mostly because it is most used in Brazil, which pay quite low in advertise.

> how can I maximize them

Fill correctly you needs by adds, your app type and what you think your user may be more interested, also place advertises in places which will not annoy user, but that he can clearly see it.

> What if no one clicks on Adds

No clicks equals not payment, but more views helps increase the price by click.

> should I use Admob meditation

I am not sure what do you mean by this.

Comment: So u mean I should expect only mere 4$ per month revenue from ads. or u r saying 4$ per active user??

Comment: 4$ is the total from the 3k active users by month.

Comment: isn't it very low?? I read story Flappy Bird earned $50k per day. I agree it ws way too famous but still if the earning is this much low, then why people add ads.

Comment: Yeah, it is really low, but I have not much users, it is in a not good location and I there was no marketing to rise the number of my users, I just let it go.

Comment: But don't get discouraged, it is really hard to have such a famous app to get rich in your first app, be sure that every good app you develop you are going to gain more users in each of your apps, and they will give monthly profit for a long time. Also knowledge is 'unbuyable'.

Comment: hmm. Publishing the game. Lets hope for the best

Comment: Post your game link... and wont you check my answer as correct?

Comment: marked it as answer now, was hoping that someone would answer me about "Admob ads meditation". link to my game: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ids.up.android